# does @NotBlank and/or @NotEmpty map to not null in database like @NotNull does in Spring JPA?

Tags: spring, postgresql, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa

First I'm using

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Is that the recommended way to use for validation in a Spring boot application?

Meaning, does this add `javax-api` and `hibernate-validator` and the required dependencies for validation?

Secondly my main question, does all three of `@NotBlank` , `@NotEmpty` and `@NotNull` map to `NOT NULL` constraint?

If not what should be used to have the validation of `@NotBlank` (trimming and making sure length is more than 0) and the `NOT NULL` constraint on the column?

should it be like below? so in this case I cannot omit the column annotation.

```
@NotBlank
@Column(nullable = false)
private String property;
```

Or should it be like below, where I use `@Size` with `@NotNull`?

```
@NotNull
@Size(min = 1)
private String property;
```

Answer (score 0):

Javax.validations can be applied to both entities as well as in DTOs. In the case of entities, we can both use @NotNull and @NonEmpty for private String property;
It will not add any constraints in the database, as these constraints will be handled at persistence level.
Error message will be like: Could not commit JPA transaction; nested exception is javax.persistence.RollbackException: Error while committing the transaction

Comment: Thanks, so using "@NotNull" to have the "NOT NULL" constraint and "@NotBlank" to ensure it has a value (not just empty string with a space like "@NotEmpty" does)?, is this better than using "@NotNull" with "@Column(nullable = false)"?

Comment: Yes, it better than @NotNull with @Column(nullable = false) if db operation are done through java code